# A special symbol

Tags: symbols

do any of you know how to make the last symbol in this formula, the one that looks like an I.

[image]

Comment: `$\mathcal{I}$`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As already commented above, you can try `$\mathcal{I}$`. Note that you can always use [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or the [Comprehensive List](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/) to look up symbols ...

Comment: Thank you very much!